# static constexpr template array member recursively required by itself

Tags: c++11, templates, constexpr

I want an `static constexpr` array of class-elements inside an templated class similar to the following code:

```
struct Element {
    unsigned i;
    constexpr Element (unsigned i) : i(i) { }
};

template <bool Reverse>
struct Template {
     static constexpr Element element[] = {
         Element (Reverse ? 1 : 0),
         Element (Reverse ? 0 : 1),
     };
};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    return Template<true>::element[0].i;
}
```

Of course, the actual `Element` structure is more complex than in this example, but it already shows the problem. If I compile this wit `gcc` I get an error about a recursive dependency:

```
test.cc: In instantiation of ‘constexpr Element Template<true>::element [2]’:
test.cc:11:27:   recursively required from ‘constexpr Element Template<true>::element [2]’
test.cc:11:27:   required from ‘constexpr Element Template<true>::element [2]’
test.cc:20:2:   required from here
test.cc:11:27: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
  static constexpr Element element[] = {
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

First of all I am curious how to circumvent this error but would also be glade if I could get a hint into the cause of this or why such a construct should not be valid...

Comment: What version of GCC have you got? I cannot reproduce with any compiler.

Comment: i have tested `g++-5.4.0`. I just noticed, that the compiler does not fail, if I only use the excerpt from above. I have to use `Template<bool>::element` afterwards..

Comment: Seems like a bug of the compiler. As a workaround, [it works](https://godbolt.org/g/yDMmWt) with `std::array`.

Comment: Now I am able to repro it try....http://rextester.com/YDN72048

Comment: @Jonas, is the real code using <bool R> as the template? maybe just specialize it?

Answer (score -2):

You need to specify the size of your Element array. `Element element[]` isn't valid c++.

```
template <bool Reverse>
struct Template {
     static constexpr Element element[2] = {
         Element (Reverse ? 1 : 0),
         Element (Reverse ? 0 : 1),
     };
};
```

Comment: explicitly specify the size does not make the error go away :(

Comment: seems like it works with `gcc-6.1` [link](https://godbolt.org/g/SnxSSb) but not with versions prior.

Comment: Not required. working fine.http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang